# How to make input language "stick" to the program only in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, input-languages

In the previous version of Windows, if you have multiple input languages, changing the input language of a particular program will only change the input in that program. For example if I have notepad open and I switched the input language to Japanese (and my default input language is English) then the input for Notepad would be in Japanese however if I open a Word document after in Word, the input language would be English.

This feature seems to have changed in Windows 10 and now the change in input language is more "global" in nature. For example if I switch the input to Japanese now if I open Word or Firefox or any other program, the input language is now set to Japanese.

This is a big hassle for me since I often works with multiple languages. I am just wondering if there is any way we can change this setting so as to "localize" the language changes to the program that is currently being used only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to achieve the desired outcome:

- Press Windows key, search for "language" in task bar search box, and
  chose "Language - control panel". (Alternatively, open "Control Panel" >
  "Language")
- On the left side of the window click "Advanced settings".
- Click the "Let me set a different input method for each app window"
  option.

[image: Screenshot of advaced language settings]

Comment: Or from PowerShell ` Set-WinLanguageBarOption -UseLegacyLanguageBar -UseLegacySwitchMode`

Comment: Also note that it can freez the system for a bit.

Comment: in windows 10 search for this keyword: "Settings: input method for each app window"